# I want to prove that for a triangle by side $a, b, c $, Inradius is:$\dfrac{2S}{P}$. Such that $S$ is area and $p$ is semiperimeter.

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I want to prove that for a triangle by side $a, b, c $, Inradius is:$$r=\dfrac{S}{P}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)}{a+b+c}}$$. Such that $S$ is area and $P$ is semiperimeter. but I cant prove it. Thank you.http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inradius.html

Comment: Do you know Heron's formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers you find useful **and** [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

For the first part i.e.  $r = \frac{S}{P}$,

[image]

Since $S = \frac{1}{2} a r +  \frac{1}{2} b r +  \frac{1}{2} c r = P r $,

then the equation holds.

For the second parts $\frac{S}{P}= \frac 12\sqrt{\frac{(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c)}{a+b+c}}$,

by [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), $S = \sqrt{P (P-a)(P-b) (P-c)}$.

Substitute into the formula $\frac{S}{P}$ then using the definition of $P$, one will get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $I$ be the incenter of $ABC$ and $r$ be the inradius.
 Since $I$ always lies in the interior of $ABC$ (it is the common point to angle bisectors) we have:

$$ 2[ABC]=2[IAB]+2[IAC]+2[IBC]= rc+rb+ra = r(a+b+c), $$
so
$$ r=\frac{2[ABC]}{a+b+c}. $$
If we compute $[ABC]$ through [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), 
$$ r = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}{a+b+c}} $$
readily follows.